# Remove value from array, update html with new array total or '$' if no total

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have two inputs, debit and credit and on a button click they update an array named 'debits'. The debit adds positive values, the credit adds negative values.

I then sum the values in the array to a variable 'totalDebits' and use that variable to update the html of a 'totalOutput'.

My goal is to click the icon [-], and when a debit is removed subtract that value from the array and update total output. When a credit is removed it should add remove that negative value from the array.

I tried using the splice.() and .inArray() methods, but for some reason when I remove the debit it empties the entire array.

Here is the snippet that I tried, as well as a jsFiddle so you can see the problem.

```
    //CLOSE BUT NO CIGAR, -
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
            $(document).on('click','.fa-minus-square',
            function() 
            {

              var thisVal = Number($(this).parent().attr('value'));

              if ($(this).parent().hasClass('debitItem')){

                    debits.splice($.inArray(thisVal, debits) ,1 );

                    $(this).parent().remove();

                    console.log(debits);

              } else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('creditItem')) {

                    debits.splice($.inArray(-thisVal, debits) ,1 );

                    $(this).parent().remove();

              };

            }

);
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/agraymd/pbtof136/4/

It seems to do what I want when looking at the console, but after it removes the value of the clicked debit it just keeps removing until the array is empty.

I can get to the point where it updates totalOutput by myself, but I removed that portion of the code since it wasn't updating the array correctly.

I hope that I'm being clear in my explanation and using the correct terminology. I'm still a newb :)

---

---

Here is a new fiddle where I add the reverse value of the debit or credit into the debits array instead of removing it. I feel like removing it would be better though. https://jsfiddle.net/agraymd/pbtof136/

---

Comment: Be careful of using inArray in conjunction with splice. inArray will return -1 if there is no match in the array and passing negative numbers into splice will still remove entries in the array, except it will start from the end of the array. Instead, you may want to add an error check and return from the function in the case that the clicked credit/debit does not match any items in the array (i.e. inArray returns -1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unbind the existing onclick event handler before setting on the entire matched set. It is as if the button gets clicked again for n times(n = the number of entries added after this), but actually the function is called again n times, because it was assigned to the click event n times.

Change this:

```
 $(document).on('click','.fa-minus-square',
        function() 
        {
         ...
        });
```

to:

```
$('.fa-minus-square').unbind().click(function() 
            {
              ...
            });
```

I have made appropriate changes in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cowdd/fx53job8/2/).

Comment: sweet! Thanks man. It's funny, that's exactly what I found I had to do after I changed the code to simply add the value or its additive inverse in the second fiddle at the bottom of the original post. Didn't think to try it for the removal. I need to study functions more, because I don't understand how it was linking twice. Is it bad practice to do the unbind bind? I read elsewhere that indicates there's a deeper problem somewhere. Is it because I'm including it with the first click function to use its variables, when I should instead define the variables wider scope and separate functions?

Comment: It was happening because every time an entry was added you assigned the handler to every `.fa-minus-square` (again). Unbind is good as it also gets rid of any default actions, so you are just resetting the elements to this one thing.